# Oracle - Error 'Table or View does not exists' when selecting tables of other schema inside a procedure creation

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, oracle11g

I have 2 schemas in my Oracle 11g DB, `APPRUNNER` and `APPOWNER`. All tables are created in `APPOWNER` and granted to `APPRUNNER`. `APPRUNNER` has synonyms to all tables in `APPOWNER`. I can select any table using `APPRUNNER` just fine but when I create a procedure that has a select statement on the tables, it fails with error `ORA-00942: table or view does not exist`.

**Note:** I can run the create procedure statement in `SQL Windows` of *PL/SQL Developer* successfully. The error occurred only in *SQLPLUS*. But I need to use *SQLPLUS* to deliver to procedure.

Following shows the result as mentioned.

```
-- Owner of the table.
SQL> select owner from all_tables where table_name = 'USR_ACCOUNT';
OWNER
------------------------------
APPOWNER

-- Synonym to the table
SQL> select * from tab where tname = 'USR_ACCOUNT';
TNAME                          TABTYPE  CLUSTERID
------------------------------ ------- ----------
USR_ACCOUNT                    SYNONYM 

-- Can select table just fine.
SQL> select account_id from usr_account where rownum = 1;
ACCOUNT_ID
-------------
10001081

-- Create procedure has error.
SQL> create or replace procedure my_procedure is
2  v number;
3  begin
4  select 1 into v from usr_account where rownum = 1;
5  dbms_output.put_line(v);
6  end my_procedure;
7  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors

-- The error.
SQL> show error;
Errors for PROCEDURE APPRUNNER.MY_PROCEDURE:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------
4/22     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
4/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

SQL> show user;
User is "apprunner"
```

Could you please suggest if I missed something?

Comment: If it works in SQL Developer but not in SQL\*Plus, then you are using a different user in SQL\*Plus

Comment: I don't think so, I have verified the user: SQL> show user;
User is "apprunner". I will update this in the post.

Comment: How have the privileges been granted?  Are the grants direct or via a role?  I'll wager that the grants are through a role which would not be available in a definer's rights stored procedure.  In `SQL*Plus`, if you do `SQL> set role none`, can you still query the table?  If not, then you just need to grant the access directly to `appruner` rather than through a role.

Comment: @Justin Cave, it is exactly as you suggested. The privileges of APPRUNNER are grant through roles. I did `set role none` and then could not select any table.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your schema name in your statament.

`select 1 into v from` **app_runner.**`usr_account where rownum = 1;`

Answer (score -3):

APPRUNNER can't create procedure because it doesn't own that schema.

Still if you want other user (in this case apprunner) to create procedure in schema, following are the 2 steps which can enable other users to create procedure :-

1.) Grant it CREATE ANY PROCEDURE system privilege.

!!**Caution**!! It is extremely powerful privilege. With this grant a user can create procedure in any schema except SYS. It is not recommended to grant this privilege to avoid possible security violation.

2.) Other user must have EXECUTE privilege on procedure(s), if any, that are called from inside procedure being created. Here in your case this is not the case.

So in your case you would need to follow step1 for apprunner user which is a very risky option and not recommended. You can further track about what is happening to verify the same using following

alter session set sql_trace = true;

Comment: Owning an object is not required.  `create any procedure` is wildly powerful and shouldn't be granted to a non-DBA.  It would only help if you used it to create the procedure in a more privileged schema (i.e. `appowner`) but if the goal was to do that, just have `appowner` create the priivilege.  There is no `execute` privilege on tables, there is no `create grant` privilege.  The owner of the procedure only needs `select` access on the table.  It just needs to be a direct grant.

Comment: Oracle user can create object into own schema if he has grants like `CREATE PROCEDURE` etc.  He doesn't necessarily have to have grants like `CREATE ANY PROCEDURE`.

Comment: Actually after mentioning answer as "APPRUNNER can't create procedure because it doesn't own that schema."  I was trying to cover general details about possible workaround which is not recommended. Sorry that I didn't mention the same explicitly to be more clear and also some mistakes in details for point 2. Now I have correct details.